# How can I get a changeable function argument structure in C++?

Tags: c++, c

My question is related to the arguments in a C++ function. Sometimes, you may expect that the  one function can accept different kinds of arguments, and as far as I am considered this can be realized in two ways. One is to use the C++ new feature: function overloading (Polymorphism), and the other is to use the 'C' function way, which is illustrated in the following examples:

```
struct type0
{
    int a;
};

struct type1
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

struct type2
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

void fun(int type, void *arg_structure)
{
    switch (type)
    {
    case 0:
        {
            struct type0 *mytype = (struct type0 *)(arg_structure);
            cout<<"a = "<<mytype->a<<endl;
            break;
        }

    case 1:
        {
            struct type1 * mytype= (struct type1 *)(arg_structure);
            cout<<"b = "<<mytype->b<<endl;
            break;
        }
    case 2:
        {
            struct type2 *mytype = (struct type2 *)(arg_structure);
            cout<<"c = "<<mytype->c<<endl;
            break;
        }
    default:
        break;
    }
}

int main () 
{
    struct type2 temp;
    temp.a = 1;
    temp.b = 2;
    temp.c = 3;
    fun(2,(void*)(&temp));

    return 0;
}
```

My question is: are there other ways of obtaining a changeable function argument structure in C++?Thanks!

Comment: [Templates?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Templates) And function overloading is not a "new" feature, it's been in C++ almost from the start.

Comment: Have you read about templates?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Almost from the start?

Comment: Function overloading is being able to call different versions of function, based upon different types, number or order of parameters. In contrast, polymorphism is calling member function of a class based upon the type of object, rather than the type of containing pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you ask for 'changeable argument structure' and not 'changeable argument type', I would assume that you are asking for flexibility in terms of types AND number of arguments.

If so, you can use [variadic functions](http://cplus.about.com/od/learningc/ss/clessonsix_5.htm):

```
void fn ( int cnt_params, ... ) {...}
```

or, if you have a compiler supporting C++11, [variadic templates](http://insanecoding.blogspot.com/2010/03/c-201x-variadic-templates.html):

```
template <typename T, typename ...P>
void fn (T t, P ...p) {....}
```

Otherwise, you can use overloading or templates, as others have already suggested.

Comment: variadic? here? why? templates is enough

Comment: My understanding of the question is that OP wants to support more flexible argument structure, i.e. not just argument types, but also the number of args. Quite possible I got it wrong :)

Comment: Where in the question did you read about variable number of arguments?

Comment: As I wrote: he asks for 'changeable argument structure' and not 'changeable argument type' where I would naturally suggest overloading or templates. 'changeable argument structure' to me sounds more like 'printf'. YMMV

Comment: I think it might just be a missunderstanding concerning the use of `struct`-ure.

Comment: That could easily be true, but just in case I would like to keep this answer available, as others have already covered the other option.

Comment: @stefan The OP himself gives examples with variable number of arguments.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways in C++ to pass different kind of parameters to same function. First you must decide when the actual type of parameter is determined - in compile-time or in run-time?
Depending on this decision you can use appropriate method to pass it:

**For compile-time (static) argument type**:

- [Function overloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading)
- [Function templates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template)

These methods are type safe and must be prefererred.

**For run-time (dynamic) argument type**:

- [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/variant.html)
- [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/any.html)
- [Unions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union)
- [Variadic functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic)
- [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) (on polymorphic base type pointer/or reference)
- [`static_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) (on pointer to `void`)

I would like to recommend to use `boost::variant` or `boost::any` for type safety they provide. Other methods are not type safe and usually are considered as bad design decision. Don't use them unless you really need it - or better improve your design to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing some things. function overloading is something completely different than polymorphism.

There is also another c way which is variable argument list. Explained for example [here](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter9/stdarg.html). I believe `printf()` brotherhood is implemented using this mechanism.

In `c++` you can use pretty much any container like `std::vector` or set in place of array,  also `std::map<string,Type>` might be nice for named arguments.

If you need set of mixed types, you can use boost's [`tuples`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_users_guide.html) (+ overloading if needed).

`c++` Templating mechanism might be usefull.

I think standard containers, tuples, templates and overloading and their combinations cover 99% of use-cases for handling arguments.

Comment: Function overloading *is* a type of polymorphism, where a single name can refer to different implementations depending on the context. It is sometimes called "static polymorphism", because the choice of the appropriate behavior is performed statically (i.e., at compile-time), as opposed to dynamic polymorphism (virtual methods), which happens at runtime.

Comment: Well I thought that polymorphism in `c++` context is used for mechanisms that provides utility of having different execution paths for **exactly the same language constucts**. And static polymorphism would fit more for templates... Well OK, I would agree that overloading fits, but only in conjuction with templates. Otherwise at the time of writing you know precisely which call path will be executed. That is not polymorphism in my opinion, as it does not introduce anything abstract, only convenience.